How do we reconcile scriptures about the four corners of the earth with the understanding that tzitzit should only be worn on four-cornered garments?
In Yeshayahu (Isaiah) 11:12, the earth is described as having four 'corners.' The word for corners used here is "kanaph," (corners or extremities) which is the same word used in Bamidbar (Numbers) 15:38 for the corners of the garment.
How do we reconcile the understanding that tzitzit should only be worn on four-cornered garments with this scriptural description of earth, a sphere, as having four corners?
I have yet to see presenting the general directions of N, S, E, and W as a valid answer because we don't see any historical or cultural references to these directions as 'corners' or 'extremities' of the earth in any other literature, language, or custom, that I am aware of.
I'm not sure how, without reconciling these scriptures, we can validate the understanding that tzitzit can only be worn on a four-cornered garment.
Any insights and sources are much appreciated!

How does the definition of "corners of the earth" have any bearing on tzitizis?

@shmosel If a spherical object with no actual corners is described by scripture as having four corners, this presents us with three possibilities:

Our interpretation of Bemidbar is flawed.
Our interpretation of Yeshayahu is flawed.
Neither is flawed. They are using the same term in different ways.

All of these possibilities require proof.

The prophets use figurative language all the time; it's not intended in a legal capacity. E.g. early in Melachim, it says "the earth broke apart from the sounds of joy."

@Shalom absolutely, I just find this specific terminology to be interesting and has been causing me to scratch my head for several days now. Is there a way we are certain the usage of "kanaph" in the context of tzitzit refers specifically to 'corners' rather than the more general 'extremities?' Please forgive me if this is an ignorant question.

It's fair to ask what the meaning is in Yeshayahu, but if you're going to fundamentally redefine words on that basis, you might as well ask whether "four" means 4.

@shmosel Maybe my logic is off or I'm not communicating it correctly. I'm not attempting to redefine words; rather, I am questioning our understanding of their meaning and application. I'm not implying that the traditional understanding is wrong, but I am asking how we arrived there. How are we certain that the mitzvah regarding tzitzit wasn't pertaining to general 'extremities' of any garment but that they must specifically be worn on a garment with at least four corners? Again, if the earth can have four 'corners' or 'extremities' as a spherical object, why couldn't any standard garment?
